# How do you set the username that Mercurial uses for commits?

Tags: mercurial

When I commit something in Mercurial like this:

```
hg commit -m "username question"
```

I see this output:

```
No username found, using 'WindowsVistaAdmin@ChunkyMonkey' instead
```

`ChunkyMonkey` is my Windows machine name and obviously `WindowsVistaAdmin` is the user that I am signed in as on this machine.

How can I set the username to something more respectable, or, at least, more concise?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

In your `~/.hgrc` (*nix) or `mercurial.ini` (Windows) file:

```
[ui]
username = First Last <email@address.com>
```

(`mercurial.ini` is in `C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\` for XP and lower, `C:\Users\[username]\` for Vista and higher. You can also run `hgtk userconfig` if you have TortoiseHg installed and do it that way.)

Comment: On OSX 10.8, I had to make the .hgrc file myself.

Comment: For versions 2.0 and up, the TortoiseHg command has changed to `thg`.

Comment: If you installed mercurial with snap on *nix, you will need to put .hgrc in ~/snap/mercurial/current. Interesting how it's contained as such.

Answer (score 34):

you can specify your username on the command line directly if you want to using --config. eg

```
hg --config ui.username=frymaster -m "comment here" commit
```

in fact, you can override anything in your .hgrc with this command. just look at your .hgrc and note the format:

```
[section]
key=val
```

that translates directly to

```
hg --config section.key=val
```

Comment: Perfect for inserting another developer's changes into the repo!

Comment: For what possible reason is this not in mercurial's documentation/help? I thought I could do this, but almost resolved to thinking mercurial was just retarded and didn't allow it when I didn't find it via `hg config -h`, `hg config -h --verbose`, `hg help config`, nor online at https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#config

Comment: Oh... nevermind. You said `--config` rather than `config`: it's an option for other commands, used for command-level overriding... still not what I want. GRRR....Why can't I just type `hg config -l ui.username=username for this repo`. This would allow for the easy implementation of identity-setting aliases: `[alias] identity1=config -l ui.username=my prewritten user info all ready to be designated for use on of many newly cloned repos with various identities associated`.

Answer (score 16):

Information from [here](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-the-basics.html):

> Setting up a username
>
> When you try to run hg commit for the
>   first time, it is not guaranteed to
>   succeed. Mercurial records your name
>   and address with each change that you
>   commit, so that you and others will
>   later be able to tell who made each
>   change. Mercurial tries to
>   automatically figure out a sensible
>   username to commit the change with. It
>   will attempt each of the following
>   methods, in order:
>
> 1. If you specify a -u option to the hg commit command on the command
>      line, followed by a username, this is
>      always given the highest precedence.
> 2. If you have set the HGUSER environment variable, this is checked
>      next.
> 3. If you create a file in your home directory called .hgrc, with a
>      username entry, that will be used
>      next. To see what the contents of this
>      file should look like, refer to the
>      section called “Creating a Mercurial
>      configuration file” below.
> 4. If you have set the EMAIL environment variable, this will be
>      used next.
> 5. Mercurial will query your system to find out your local user name and
>      host name, and construct a username
>      from these components. Since this
>      often results in a username that is
>      not very useful, it will print a
>      warning if it has to do this.
>
> If all of these mechanisms fail,
>   Mercurial will fail, printing an error
>   message. In this case, it will not let
>   you commit until you set up a
>   username.
>
> You should think of the HGUSER
>   environment variable and the -u option
>   to the hg commit command as ways to
>   override Mercurial's default selection
>   of username. For normal use, the
>   simplest and most robust way to set a
>   username for yourself is by creating a
>   .hgrc file; see below for details.

Comment: is there a possibility to set a username by repository ?

Comment: @edomaur , yes it is, you must edit the `./hg/hgrc` file in the repository in question, where you need to set `username = Dev server` in the `[ui]` section

Answer (score 6):

Here is how my windows /users/xxx/mercurial.ini looks. I don't have to enter username or passwords for anything. Looks like it might be repo specific. I have tortoiseHG installed, not sure if that makes any difference.

```
[ui]
username=mbroekhuis

[auth]
repo.prefix=http://myrepo
repo.username=mbroekhuis
repo.password=secret
```

Comment: I don't think having your password in plaintext is a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone trying to use HG workbench

settings

[image]

user global settings

[image]

Edit File

[image]

Save