# Supplying username and password for mercurial

Tags: mercurial

So I am trying to commit changes to a repository but it tells me
abort: no username supplied
(use 'hg config --edit' to set your username).
So type in 'hg config --edit' on my mac terminal, but I don't know what key to press to save changes and then exit out the window after entering in my name.

Comment: It is impossible to answer this without knowing which text editor is involved, but if it is a graphical editor, you can simply use its menus to save and then quit. All that `hg config --edit` does is opening the  configuration file(s) in an appropriate editor, and so there is no real difference with respect to how you ordinarily use said editor to save files. (Disclaimer: I am not at all familiar with Macs and OS X.)

Comment: The editor to be used for editing the configuration is specified in the configuration itself. For example on my Ubuntu when I do this `hg config --edit` it opens my <home>/.hgrc with vi, and I can see a line `editor = vi`. You can even set your username with the config command: `hg --config ui.username=<your name>`, [thanks to that post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401803/how-do-you-set-the-username-that-mercurial-uses-for-commits)